# How can I reuse a HBITMAP handle?

Tags: c, winapi

I have to draw a bitmap multiple times. It's loaded from file. I can reload it every time I have to use it in `SelectObject` the following way:

```
void drawBitmap(HWND hWnd, int xPos, int yPos) {
    HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBmp);
    BitBlt(hDC, xPos, yPos, 7, 7, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
drawBitmap(hMainWnd, 0, 0);
drawBitmap(hMainWnd, 14, 0);
drawBitmap(hMainWnd, 28, 0);
```

But is it also possible to do something like this?

```
HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
void drawBitmap(HWND hWnd, int xPos, int yPos) {
    HBITMAP hBmp2 = hBmp;
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBmp2);
    BitBlt(hDC, xPos, yPos, 7, 7, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
drawBitmap(hMainWnd, 0, 0);
drawBitmap(hMainWnd, 14, 0);
drawBitmap(hMainWnd, 28, 0);
```

But this only draws one bitmap...

MSDN says:

> The `SelectObject` function selects an
>   object into the specified device
>   context (DC). The new object replaces
>   the previous object of the same type.

So maybe my `hBmp` is wasted after `SelectObject` is called. But I copied it into `hBmp2` first, then what's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not deleting the memory DC when you are done with it. That means the DC is leaked, and the bitmap is still selected in that leaked DC. And according to the `SelectObject` documentation: "An application cannot select a single bitmap into more than one DC at a time."

So the second `SelectObject` fails because the bitmap is still selected in the first `HDC`.

Clean up after yourself by calling `DeleteDC` at the end of the `drawBitmap` function (and also call `DeleteObject` on the hBmp when you are done with it).

Additionally, the `HBITMAP hBmp2 = hBmp;` line accomplishes nothing. You're just assigning the handle to a different variable. It's still the same handle to the same bitmap.

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick. I'll accept your answer, I only have to wait 5 mins for some reason.

Comment: On a side note, you could further optimize this code by reusing the memory DC itself instead of just the bitmap (still delete it after you are done with it, of course).

Comment: Everything's correct, except possibly one thing: I'm not certain, but I think that when you delete a DC it destroys the selected bitmap as well. So that if you still have a handle to this bitmap - it's invalid. A more correct thing would be to save the retval of `SelectObject`, and then, just before you destry the DC call `SelectObject` again with that value, so that you restore the original bitmap to the DC (which is 1x1 monochrome bitmap). Is this true?

Comment: There is nothing mentioned in the documentation of DeleteDC about deleting selected objects, so I don't think so.